# Works Fine on all broswer except IE*

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

ive tried to sort this out, but with no success.. Having problems in IE8.. it keeps saying JSObject expected but cant seem to work out what the problem is as it works fine everywhere else..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
console.log('here');
// Profile Selector

// Get all the big profile elements listed above.
// Transform the result of `getElementsByTagName` from a NodeList
// to an Array. Just good practice, really.

var profileWrapper = document.getElementById('profileWrapper');

var bigElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    profileWrapper.getElementsByTagName('div')
);

// Find an element in the `bigElements` array above that
// has a className that contains the `id` argument.
function selectBigElement( id ) {

    // loop thru all the elements in `bigElements`, and...
    for( var i = 0; i < bigElements.length; ++i ) {

        // ... if the current element's className contains the
        // query string argument (`id`), then show it...
        if( ~bigElements[i].className.indexOf( id ) ) {
            bigElements[i].style.display = 'block';
        }

        // ... Otherwise, hide it.
        else {
            bigElements[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

};

$('.mini_profile').mouseover(function(event) {
    selectBigElement(this.id);
});

selectBigElement( 179 );
});
```

Comment: Remove `console.log('here');` then try. `console` is only available when console window is open

Comment: Why do you mix vanilla js and jquery?

Comment: Did IE8 come with the indexOf function?

Comment: @cstruter IE8 supports the `String.prototype.indexOf()` method but not the `Array.prototype.indexOf()`.

Comment: Just a comment: One big issue with this code: You are using jQuery, which does all the nasty work of exposing an API which works consistently across all browsers so that you don't need to worry about it, and then you use some basic DOM stuff which isn't supported in IE8. If you are going to use jQuery, use everything it provides.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your code, you're using a few methods that aren't supported:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(profileWrapper.getElementsByTagName('div'));
```

This attempts to convert a `NodeList` to an `Array`. This is unsupported in IE8 as it won't support NodeLists as host Objects.

For the regular `for` loop you don't need to do this as you can loop over the NodeList like an Array (excluding `Array.prototype.forEach()`), just simply remove the `Array.prototype.slice.call()` method and stick with:

```
var bigElements = profileWrapper.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

You are *however* attempting to use `indexOf`, which is ECMAScript 5 and also an `Array.prototype` method. To get IE8 support, you'll need to Polyfill the two implementations or write some wrapper functions to get the same result(s).